# How To Use Variable In Javascript Code Ex: src="htp://www.url.com/file.php?id=[3434]"

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I'm running a wordpress multisite network where I give users an options page with different settings to make their page unique.

I would like to implement a GetResponse optin form on their page.

In the options page I have a field where they can put in their GetResponse FormID - which is usually 6 numbers (422125).

The getresponse form looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://app.getresponse.com/view_webform.js?wid=422125&mg_param1=1"></script>
```

I need to be able to change 422125 to whatever id they set within their options page.

I already have the php code written that calls the id from the options page, but I can't figure out how to set it within the javascript.

Any help would be greatly appreciated... Thank you for your time!

Comment: on a PHP page you can do `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://app.getresponse.com/view_webform.js?wid=<?php echo $form_id ?>&mg_param1=1"></script>`

Comment: I thought I tried this before but it didn't work. After retrying it again, it worked this time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on a PHP page you can do the following and it will echo `$form_id` as the `wid` parameter of the url.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://app.getresponse.com/view_webform.js?wid=<?php echo $form_id ?>&mg_param1=1"></script>
```